# Relation extraction using doccano

Tags: extract, bert-language-model, relation, spacy-3, doccano

I want to do relation extraction using doccano. I have already annotated data/entity relation using doccano and exported data is in jsonl format. I want to convert it into spacy format data to train bert using spacy on jsonl annotated data.
.

Answer (score 1):

Drop this Annotation and go with NER Annotator spacy (reannotate it)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).